# Hiding overflow

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the background of my left menu to be the length of the page all the time.
This is how a friend suggested I went about it but it's not working for me.

HTML

```
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <nav class="DynamicNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="AboutMeContact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="AboutMeEducation.html">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="AboutMeWork.html">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="AboutMeHobbies.html">Hobbies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.DynamicNav{
    background:rgb(40,40,40);
    padding-bottom: 3000px;
    margin-bottom: -2990px;
    width:200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height:800px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    float:left;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

you can see it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Hpc/)

This still makes the background incredibly long.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure i'm understanding the question, but try this :

```
.DynamicNav{
    background:rgb(40,40,40);
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width:200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height:800px;
    margin-top:-20px;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

With the height at 100% the left menu is always taking 100%...